# Observable.merge only shows results from one stream using RxDart

Tags: dart, flutter

```
 Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream() {
     List<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> streamList = [];
     for (var id in idArray) {
         Stream<QuerySnapshot> x = photosReference.where("creatorId", isEqualTo: id).snapshots();
         streamList.add(x);
     }
     var x = Observable.merge(streamList);
     return x;
 }
```

I expect the snapshots from each query Snapshot x to appear, however, I only get snapshots from one of the streams.

Comment: How many streams are added (how many `id` are in `idArray`)? Does each of these streams return results?

Comment: 2 'id' in 'IdArray'. And in the 'streamList' I also get 2 streams, HOWEVER, for some reason, the results are only from one stream. And yes, individually, each stream does show results.

Comment: I would it expect to work then. Don't know what the issue could be.

Comment: I'll double check the stream results...thanks

Comment: Am I handling the Observable correctly? Do I need to initiate it first?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this. Keep getting one stream only. If I reverse the idArray, then a different  stream appears, meaning all the streams are there, but for some reason I am only getting the last one.

Comment: Try with own streams. It might have to do with the streams being filled from a plugin over MethodChannel.

Comment: These are firestore streams. Would that have anything to do with it?